# I need to display a page using a button

Tags: html

I have been working on a project with plain html and no web servers that requires me to navigate to different parts of the project for example the quiz on different pages. I want to click a button then be tooken to that part and I have searched for ways to do that but found nothing heres what I have. I really need help on this one because I am pretty much stuck.

```
<button id='quiz' onclick="QuizFunction()" type="button" style="hight: 25px; width: 100px">Avalanche Quiz!</button><br>
```

Ive tried various things with the javascript varying from

```
function QuizFunction(){ document.write("entire 500 line quiz code here")
```

To

```
 document.GetElementById"quiz"InnerHTML/same big quiz code here/
```

I really need help on this one!

Comment: It's good you've shown initiative that you are trying, however the question still reads really vague and it is hard to understand exactly what you are after.  If you can clarify more that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to change the page (your question is vague)

Why can't you just use a link?

```
<a href="avalanche_quiz.html">
  <button type="button">Avalanche Quiz!</button>
</a>
```

This would give you the native button whilst wrapped in a link.

Using JavaScript to handle something so simple just seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location):

```
function QuizFunction(){ window.location.replace("filename.html"); }
```

Comment: You are a god thanks alot! This will help me out with other stuff!

Comment: If you are just using a function to change the page why not just use an `<a>` tag?

Comment: @Lavabeams I had the same thought. I assume the OP wants the "button style" rather than a link. Otherwise, yeah, that's a whole lot easier.